# Unable to start JOnAs service

Tags: linux, debian

I'm having problems with my Debian 6.0.3 (Squeeze) server
We run an application that uses JOnAs service

usually when its not working I run 
/etc/init.d/jonas start

When I do it at the moment I get an error saying:
Removing Jonas working files
I've stopped and restarted the service and server but no joy.

I'm afraid this is the limit to my knowledge on this product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

David

Comment: 2015-06-10 11:14:31,183 : WARN : jonas Main : JmxServiceImpl.doStart :    Cannot start JMX service javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]

Answer (score 0):

Run /etc/init.d/jonas start Error when starting the service says: Removing Jonas working files I tired /etc/init.d/jonas restart No joy Try ping the gateway 10.x.x.x and if its replying, try ping 127.0.0.1 The Java processes are all linked to Localhost which is 127.0.0.1 Check the localhost exists by running command Ifconfig If you need to start the service run: ifconfig lo up Then run: /etc/init.d/jonas start